# Trying to use the .previous() method on a UCanAccess ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am working on batching information from Facebook. 
I have decided that the best way to get to the result i want is to have 2 loops , while both are about if my resultset has `.next()` ....

The problem is that ResultSets don't have a `hasNext()` method but only `next()`.
So I've tried to move back after the first `.next()` method using `.previous()` and I get a "feature not supported" error.

So I've tried again just after the second `.next()` and it says the same thing....

It seems you cannot use `.previous()` under UCanAccess.

The exception is -

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: feature not supported
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.previous(UcanaccessResultSet.java:933)
```

code part -

```
int i = 1;
        try {
        idsLoop:while(rs.next()){
            if(i==1){
                rs.previous();
            }
            if(i<50){
                idsForRequest.add(rs.getString("Expr1"));
                i++;
                }
                else{
                    i=1;
                    break idsLoop; 
                }
```

BTW if anyone is wondering why I'm doing it like that , is because I don't want to batch more than 50 pages at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDBC Statement objects default to `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` under UCanAccess (and most, if not all, JDBC drivers) so `rs.previous()` will fail if you do something like

```java
try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
    try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql)) {
        // ...
        rs.previous();  // <- error
```

However, if you specify a scrollable ResultSet when you create the Statement object ...

```java
try (Statement st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)) {
    try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql)) {
        // ...
        rs.previous();  // <- no error
```

... then `rs.previous()` will work.